Terraform deployment failure on constructing REST client
Currently working on a deployment for Flink's kubernetes operator on GCP, facing an issue where it's saying that terraform cannot construct a rest client due to no client config.
╷
│ Error: Failed to construct REST client
│ 
│   with kubernetes_manifest.flink_cluster,
│   on main.tf line 95, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "flink_cluster":
│   95: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "flink_cluster" {
│ 
│ cannot create REST client: no client config

The part of the schema where its failing looks like this, I don't think its a provider issue either since this provider schema worked on other deployments:
# Create Flink Session Cluster using CRD
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "flink_cluster" {
  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "flinkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    kind       = "FlinkDeployment"
    metadata = {
      name      = "flink-session-cluster"
      namespace = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name
    }
    spec = {
      image = "flink:latest"
      flinkVersion = "1.20.0"
      flinkConfiguration = {
        "taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots" = "2"
        "parallelism.default" = "2"
      }
      serviceAccount = "flink"
      jobManager = {
        replicas = 1
        resource = {
          memory = "2048m"
          cpu    = 1
        }
      }
      taskManager = {
        resource = {
          memory = "2048m"
          cpu    = 1
        }
      }
      podTemplate = {
        spec = {
          containers = [{
            name = "flink-main-container"
            env = [{
              name  = "DISABLE_JEMALLOC"
              value = "true"
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    helm_release.flink_operator,
    kubernetes_service_account.flink,
    kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.flink
  ]
}

I've tried to use depends on to let the cluster init first but it seems that was not the issue. Here is the full deployment schema:
# gcloud auth application-default login
provider "kubernetes" {
  host  = "https://${google_container_cluster.default.endpoint}"
  token = data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  client_certificate = base64decode(
    google_container_cluster.default.master_auth[0].client_certificate,
  )
  client_key = base64decode(google_container_cluster.default.master_auth[0].client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    google_container_cluster.default.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate,
  )
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "staging" {
  metadata {
    name = "staging"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_address" "default" {
  name   = var.network_name
  region = var.region
}

data "google_client_config" "current" {
}

data "google_container_engine_versions" "default" {
  location = var.location
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "default" {
  name               = var.network_name
  location           = var.location
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  min_master_version = data.google_container_engine_versions.default.latest_master_version
  network            = google_compute_subnetwork.default.name
  subnetwork         = google_compute_subnetwork.default.name

  node_config {
    machine_type = "c2-standard-4"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "sleep 90"
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary_nodes" {
  name       = "${var.network_name}-node-pool"
  location   = var.location
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.default.name
  
  initial_node_count = 1

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = 1
    max_node_count = 5
  }

  node_config {
    machine_type = "c2-standard-4"
    
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
    ]
  }
}

# Install Flink Kubernetes Operator using Helm
resource "helm_release" "flink_operator" {
  name       = "flink-operator"
  repository = "https://downloads.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-${var.flink_operator_version}/"
  chart      = "flink-kubernetes-operator"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name

  set {
    name  = "webhook.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  depends_on = [google_container_node_pool.primary_nodes]
}

# Create Flink Session Cluster using CRD
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "flink_cluster" {
  manifest = {
    apiVersion = "flinkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    kind       = "FlinkDeployment"
    metadata = {
      name      = "flink-session-cluster"
      namespace = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name
    }
    spec = {
      image = "flink:latest"
      flinkVersion = "1.16"
      flinkConfiguration = {
        "taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots" = "2"
        "parallelism.default" = "2"
      }
      serviceAccount = "flink"
      jobManager = {
        replicas = 1
        resource = {
          memory = "2048m"
          cpu    = 1
        }
      }
      taskManager = {
        resource = {
          memory = "2048m"
          cpu    = 1
        }
      }
      podTemplate = {
        spec = {
          containers = [{
            name = "flink-main-container"
            env = [{
              name  = "DISABLE_JEMALLOC"
              value = "true"
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    helm_release.flink_operator,
    kubernetes_service_account.flink,
    kubernetes_cluster_role_binding.flink
  ]
}

# Create service account for Flink
resource "kubernetes_service_account" "flink" {
  metadata {
    name      = "flink"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "flink" {
  metadata {
    name = "flink-role-binding"
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "ClusterRole"
    name      = "edit"
  }
  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = "flink"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_resource_quota" "staging" {
  metadata {
    name      = "staging-quota"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.staging.metadata[0].name
  }

  spec {
    hard = {
      "requests.cpu"    = "4"
      "requests.memory" = "16Gi"
      "limits.cpu"      = "20"
      "limits.memory"   = "128Gi"
    }
  }
}

output "load-balancer-ip" {
  value = google_compute_address.default.address
}


This may be worth filing as an issue with the kubernetes provider since, even if it is an issue with your config and not the plugin or SDK, the error message is not useful from a Terraform debugging perspective. If this occurs during apply and not plan or validate then, combined with the error message, I would suspect this is an issue with SDK interfacing.

The kubernetes_manifest resource type needs to contact the Kubernetes cluster during the planning phase to find the schema for flinkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta1.FlinkDeployment so it can validate your spec and generate an accurate prediction of what the final values will be for this resource once it's been applied.
Your provider "kubernetes" block uses the following attributes of the cluster resource which would not be known until the cluster has already been created:

google_container_cluster.default.endpoint
google_container_cluster.default.master_auth

Therefore the kubernetes_manifest implementation would not be able to contact the cluster to fetch the schema unless the cluster had already been created on a previous plan/apply round.
Although it's not directly related to the error you've observed here, I think there's a second related problem that would appear if you fixed the first problem: the FlinkDeployment CRD must also be registered with the cluster before kubernetes_manifest.flink_cluster can be planned, because otherwise the cluster wouldn't actually know the schema for that resource type.
Assuming that I'm guessing correctly that helm_release.flink_operator is the resource that would register the CRD with your cluster, you should be able to avoid both of these problems by planning and applying this initially over three plan/apply rounds:

terraform apply -target=google_container_cluster.default to first focus only on getting the cluster instantiated.
terraform apply -target=helm_release.flink_operator to then focus only on getting the CRD registered with the cluster.
terraform apply (with no special arguments) to deal with everything else, including kubernetes_manifest.flink_cluster now that the cluster is running and knows the schema for FlinkDeployment.

